# Why is a plural noun followed by present participle incorrect?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, participles, agreement

Discussing what they do to earn extra cash, a friend told me: "I get paid for dogs walking."  I think they should use the singular, "I get paid for dog walking".  My friend replied, but I always walk multiple dogs.  I don't know how to respond.

I still maintain "dogs walking" is incorrect in this context, but I can't explain why.  Are present participles (ie, "walking") always considered singular and expected to match the noun they describe (ie, "dog")?  What are the rules that govern this construction?

Comment: "dog walking" is two consecutive nouns, the first of which is being used as a ***noun adjunct***. Such nouns are nearly always singular. The only contrary example I can come up with is ***an arms race***.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. Please finish reading the [Tour] to learn about this site. In my opinion this sort of question is more appropriate on our sister site, English Language Learners. But, try not to make your question “Why?” as the answer is generally “because that’s the way English works”, it’s a language, not mathematics.

Comment: @David It’s not asking whether *dogs walking* is correct, which would be an ELL question. It’s a question by a native speaker asking the grammatical reason WHY it is not licit. That is an excellent EL&U question.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I doubt it. If he has to describe an argument with a friend and state "I still maintain…" he is asking for adjudication; and if he is asking for rules he is unlikely, in my opinion, to be a native speaker or an educated native speaker interested in grammar.

Comment: @David He may or. may not, be a ns, granted. However, the question is definitely about *why* dogs walking is ungrammatical, and as it's not straightforward (consider *ladies watch*), this makes it an eminently suitable question for EL&U (although, of course, it may be a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

In "dog walking," "walking" is not a participle modifying "dog." If it were, you would need an article ("a dog walking"), since "dog" is a count noun; this noun phrase would refer to a dog who is walking, not to the activity of dog walking.

Instead, "walking" is a verbal noun. It acts purely as a noun, and is here being modified by "dog," another noun serving as a noun adjunct. As is typically the case, the noun adjunct needs to be singular.

Incidentally: it's not a gerund either, since then it would likely take an object ("walking dogs") instead of a noun adjunct. If you interpret it as a gerund, "dogs walking" would technically make sense (with "dogs" as an accusative subject), but then it would be the dogs doing the walking, not your friend walking the dogs.

Comment: Do you think this could be a witty way of expressing what she was doing?  It is not the conventional way of saying it, perhaps, but it is fairly obvious what it means.